# OleDb Error unknown field name “Name” in visual basics

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Hey there are many question like this however i didn't find the right one. i keep on getting this error,

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpFO7.png)

i am Using
vb.net and Ms-access database.

> I have researched and didn't get anything, i checked the name "productID" and it is correct. So i dont know what wrong? Please help

My Code:

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim dbProvider As String
    Dim dbSource As String
    Dim MyDocumentsFolder As String
    Dim TheDatabase As String
    Dim FullDatabasePath As String
    Dim Sql As String
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

    Dim empty = Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().Where(Function(txt) txt.Text.Length = 0)
    If empty.Any Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill all informations")
    Else
        dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
        TheDatabase = "C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\MS Office\project.mdb"
        MyDocumentsFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
        FullDatabasePath = MyDocumentsFolder & TheDatabase
        dbSource = "Data Source = " & TheDatabase

        con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

        Sql = "INSERT INTO tblUsers (productID, quantity, price, productSection, supplierID) VALUES (@ProductID, @Quantity, @Price, @ProductSection, @SupplierID)"

        MessageBox.Show("Database is now open")
        con.Open()

        Dim command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(Sql, con)

        command.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtProductName.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", OleDb.OleDbType.Integer).Value = txtQuantity.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@Price", OleDb.OleDbType.Currency).Value = txtPrice.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@ProductSection", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtSection.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@SupplierID", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtSupplier.Text
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MessageBox.Show("Product Added Successfully")
        con.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("Database is now Closed")
    End If
End Sub
```

The error is shown in this line : `command.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct table name? Table name is tblUsers while the data looks like a product.

Comment: If you would study the tips and guidelines in [ask] and take the [tour], you might have **[fewer sockpuppet accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48195532/1070452)** to juggle...and get fewer DVs and more answers

Comment: @Han is right. You probably need to use a table with a name like `tblProduct`

Comment: Ya tbl name was wrong, Thanks @Han

Comment: And i spend ages looking for what i did wrong. Lol

Answer (score -1):

SQL is case sensitive, check if something is capitalized in your Sql variable and not capitalized in your table in SQL server or vise versa.

you can also check if the capitalization on the parameters might be causing the issue as well.

Comment: Nope, Access SQL isn't case sensitive.

Comment: ya it isn't and due to this reason i have to make it case sensitive